# default and sdbarker_tiny GUI of NSIS

Tags: user-interface, nsis

I'm trying to modify and resize the windows of default.exe which you can find in the Contrib/UI subfolder of NSIS. However, after saving the modifications to it I'm not able to see the changes in my installer's GUI.

I tried deleting default.exe only to find out that it's not the default GUI used by NSIS when you're not using MUI. My first question is, where can I find the default GUI of NSIS?

There's a smaller GUI anyway, named sdbarker_tiny.exe. My second question is, how do you use it in your installer?

Please help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default.exe is the *same* as the default UI, but the real default UI is embedded in the exeheaders in the Stubs subdirectory.

To change a page or all of the UI, use ChangeUI.

Ex: ChangeUI all "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UIs\sdbarker_tiny.exe"